# How to use the PolicyHttpMessageHandler as "standalone"?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm just trying to create a simple test where I use `DelegateHandlers` to instantiate a `HttpClient` without bringing Asp.net Core packages.
I have 2 deletage handlers

- `ThrottlingDelegatingHandler`
- `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` (from Polly package)

How can I combine both and pass to the `HttpClient`?

```
var policy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var pollyHandler = new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(policy);
var http = new HttpClient(new ThrottlingDelegatingHandler(MaxParallelism, pollyHandler));
```

The above gives me an error: `System.InvalidOperationException : The inner handler has not been assigned.`

The `PolicyHttpMessageHandler` does not have a constructor where I can pass the `innerHandler`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new Handler1(), new Handler2(), ...,new HandlerN()); ?

Comment: `HttpClientFactory` does not exist in `.net 6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `InnerHandler` in your most inner handler to `HttpClientHandler` like this:

```
var policy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError().CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var pollyHandler = new PolicyHttpMessageHandler(policy);

//New line
pollyHandler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

var http = new HttpClient(new ThrottlingDelegatingHandler(MaxParallelism, pollyHandler));
```

You basically have to set the next handler in the pipeline.

---

For reference: [this is how HttpClient is constructed if no handler is specified](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L140)

```
#region Constructors

public HttpClient() : this(new HttpClientHandler())
{
}

public HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler) : this(handler, true)
{
}

public HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler) : base(handler, disposeHandler)
{
    _timeout = s_defaultTimeout;
    _maxResponseContentBufferSize = HttpContent.MaxBufferSize;
    _pendingRequestsCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

#endregion Constructors
```

Where the `base` is the `HttpMessageInvoker` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nuget package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) which has [HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/3e2e11b5a12cd4ba42ff9b1f0d96d0ae62ae8708/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientFactory.cs) with below two factory methods. Wiring up the `InnerHandler`s when one has to deal with multiple delegatingHandlers becomes unwieldy; it's best done with some code. If you don't want a nuget dependency, it's not difficult to handroll your own `Create()` implementations.

```cs
HttpClient Create(params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
HttpClient Create(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
```